# Python script is reporting Google sheet api Quota exceed error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have below function to update my google sheet every 3 seconds.

```
def update_gsheet():
    global ce_trade_status, pe_trade_status
    while ce_trade_status != 'completed' or pe_trade_status != 'completed':
        try:
            batch_update_values = [
                {"range": "A2", "values": [[selectedCEStrike]]},
                {"range": "B2", "values": [[ce_sell_time]]},
                {"range": "C2", "values": [[ce_sell_price]]},
                {"range": "D2", "values": [[ce_sl_price]]},
                {"range": "E2", "values": [[ce_buy_time]]},
                {"range": "F2", "values": [[ce_buy_price]]},
                {"range": "G2", "values": [[ce_exit_reason]]},
                {"range": "H2", "values": [[ce_limit_price]]},
                {"range": "I2", "values": [[ltp[selectedCEStrike]]]},
                {"range": "A3", "values": [[selectedPEStrike]]},
                {"range": "B3", "values": [[pe_sell_time]]},
                {"range": "C3", "values": [[pe_sell_price]]},
                {"range": "D3", "values": [[pe_sl_price]]},
                {"range": "E3", "values": [[pe_buy_time]]},
                {"range": "F3", "values": [[pe_buy_price]]},
                {"range": "G3", "values": [[pe_exit_reason]]},
                {"range": "H3", "values": [[pe_limit_price]]},
                {"range": "I3", "values": [[ltp[selectedPEStrike]]]},
            ]
            sh.batch_update(batch_update_values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            sys.exit(1)
    time.sleep(3)
```

But I am getting below 429 error for `'WriteRequestsPerMinutePerUser'`.

```
{'code': 429, 'message': "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Write requests' and limit 'Write requests per minute per user' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXXX'.", 'status': 'RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com', 'quota_location': 'global', 'quota_limit': 'WriteRequestsPerMinutePerUser', 'consumer': 'projects/XXXX', 'quota_metric': 'sheets.googleapis.com/write_requests', 'quota_limit_value': '120'}}, {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links': [{'description': 'Request a higher quota limit.', 'url': 'https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota'}]}]}
```

My Current Quota for `WriteRequestsPerMinutePerUser` is `120` per minute. Since I am using the batch update, it has to count entire set of Cells as single request instead of individual ones.
I am not not getting how it is crossing the Quota limit even though I am putting a delay of 3 sec. How can I get rid of this issue ? (I already opened a request with Google of a Quota increase)

Answer (score 1):

RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED is flood protection it ensures that you dont flood the api. The 120 per minute includes each item with in the bach.

Batching does not save you quota or prevent against flooding errors. It just saves you the http requests.

Slow down your application.